# Unable to execute the if and fi command in bash. It will always execute the other part even if there are no Arguments

Tags: command-line, bash

Unable to execute the if command in bash. It will always execute the other part even if there are no Arguments.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0]]
then
echo "No Username Specified as Argument. Please pass username as argument"
exit
fi
sudo echo ''$1' ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y isc-dhcp-server python-qt4 woof openssh-server  sshpass freerdp-x11
```

Comment: Your script - as written - should not run at all (the `[[ . . .]]` needs whitespace after the operand i.e. `[[ $# -eq 0 ]]`). You may find www.shellcheck.net helpful for debugging it.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. The space seemed to be the issue!